# Enabling visual styles with C++ Win32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013

According to the MSDN article, visual styles are supposed to be applied to Win32 applications by default. However, the UI elements all appeared as Windows Classic until I inserted this into my header:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Now, when I try to add a button using this call:

```
CreateWindow(L"button", L"Quit",
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
120, 50, 80, 25,
hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

That looks like a Windows 8 button with Windows Classic font. Am I missing something to apply the full Windows 8 visual style?

Comment: Shot in the dark: what happens if you [specify your program as a Windows 8 program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? If this works, I'll provide an answer (assuming someone else doesn't already knwo whwere I'm going).

Comment: Did you set any fonts?

Comment: The button is themed (you can tell from the border), but it needs to be told which font to use.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would have suggested that, but [MSDN seems to imply you don't need to...?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which I think is where the OP's confusion comes from

Comment: @JonathanPotter he said he got the theme after applying the Common Controls 6 manifest but I have a feeling he's saying MSDN says you shouldn't need that on Windows 8; I think he's confused by the MSDN link I just pasted above, hence my question about the Windows 8 manifest

Comment: Visual styles don't affect the default font that controls get. You need to do what the dialog manager does and set the font explicitly.

Comment: Then MSDN is misleading in this case. I still wonder if the Windows 8 application manifest would load Common Controls 6...

Comment: The non-client area is themed automatically. Client controls must opt in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The button is themed, but you did not set a font for the button. Because of that, your button has the default font.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that fonts weren't part of the visual style! Added a font manually and it looks better.